# Getting the wrong number of elements in a dynamic array

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

I am a beginner in C and I'm trying to build a very simple dynamic array. My code compiles, but outputs the wrong size when returning the array size. For example, when I test it for a final array size of 0, it outputs 13744632839234567870, which is very big and very wrong.

I don't think my `array_size` function is wrong. I suspect it goes wrong in `append`, but I just can't find what's wrong with it.

If anyone would be willing to help me, I would be extremely grateful!

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct array
{
    long size;
    long capacity;
    int* data;
};

struct array* array_init(long initial_capacity) {
    struct array* v = malloc(sizeof(struct array)); 
    if (v==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
}    

int append(struct array *v, int elem) {
    if (v->size >= v->capacity) {

        v->capacity *= 2;
        v->data = realloc(v->data, sizeof(int) * v->capacity);
    }
    v->data[v->size] = elem;
    v->size++;
    return 0;    
}

int indexget(struct array *v, long index) {
    if (index >= v->size) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return v->data[index];
}

long array_size(struct array *v) {
    return v->size;
}
```

Comment: Where are you initializing `v->size` ?

Comment: Remember that `malloc` doesn't initialize the contents of the memory it allocates. The contents of that memory is *indeterminate* and seem like random or garbage.

Comment: malloc(0) isn't well-defined.

Comment: @Lundin `malloc(0)` is well-defined, the man page says: If size is 0, then malloc() returns either NULL, or a unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to free().

Comment: @mch No it is not well-defined, but implementation-defined. Forget about man and read C17 7.22.3 `If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_init()` did not assign anything to `.size` and `.capacity` members.

Suggested changes:

```
struct array {
    // long size;
    // long capacity;
    // `size_t` is the right-size for array indexing.
    // Be mindful that `size_t` is some _unsigned_ type.
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
    int* data;
};

// struct array* array_init(long initial_capacity) {
struct array* array_init(size_t initial_capacity) {
    struct array* v = malloc(sizeof(struct array)); 
    if (v == NULL) {
       return NULL;
    }
    v->data = malloc(sizeof(int)*initial_capacity );
    // If initial_capacity is 0, a NULL return does not certainly mean out of memory
    //if (v->data==NULL){
    if (v->data==NULL && initial_capacity != 0){
       free(v); // also free prior allocation
       return NULL;
    }

    // Add
    v->size = 0;
    v->capacity = initial_capacity;

    return v;
}
```

---

`v->capacity *= 2` is weak as it is not known that `v->capacity > 0`.

```
int append(struct array *v, int elem) {
    if (v->size >= v->capacity) {
        // v->capacity *= 2;
        v->capacity = v->capacity > 0 ? v->capacity*2 : 1;
```

---

`indexget()` is unclear.  Why imply returning a *pointer* when index is out of range?

```
#define BAD_VALUE 0  /* or some unused `int` value for the application */
int indexget(struct array *v, long index) {
    // if (index >= v->size) {  incomplete test if `index` is signed
    if (index >= v->size || index < 0) {
        // return NULL;
        return BAD_VALUE;
    }
    return v->data[index];
}
```

**or**

Is code returning the address of the element of the array?

```
//int indexget(struct array *v, long index) {
int *indexget(struct array *v, size_t index) {
    if (index >= v->size) {
        return NULL;
    }
    // return v->data[index];
    return &v->data[index];
}
```

---

`append()` lacks re-allocation success check.

```
        // v->data = realloc(v->data, sizeof(int) * v->capacity);
        void *p = realloc(v->data, sizeof(int) * v->capacity);
        if (p == NULL) {
          return EXIT_FAILURE; // Handle out-of-memory in some fashion
        }
        v->data = p;
```

Comment: Would also suggest `const`-ing the argument when applicable, i.e. in `array_size()`. Also function naming is not consistent, perhaps they should all have an `array_` prefix.